# Disable standard queries in ArcGIS Server enables sub-queries (sub-selects)?

Tags: arcgis-server, feature-service

Has anyone had success setting standardizedQueries": "false" in ArcGIS server, and then executing sub-selects within feature services? If so, was this done on standard geodatabase versioning, branch versioning features? And were the services standard Esri services or UN services?

Comment: A False query wouldn't allow for a sub-select.